# Dash-to-Dock Extension in default Gnome Fedora is Crashing

Tags: fedora, gnome, crash, theme, load

Thanks for taking a look.

I have the default Gnome Fedora installed, and having liked the Dash-to-Dock extension in Arch, I continued to use it in Fedora. Thing is, the system always report a problem after boot and then the app tray takes a long time to load icons. After which I got annoyed, so I uninstalled it from the https://extensions.gnome.org/, and then I git cloned it and compiled it myself, which seemed to work fine, yielding no errors or problem, with improved icon loading time after boot. Though still slower than Arch, which is instantaneous. Another problem now surfaced though, the thing is I have to disable pressure to show since it will disappear after me pressuring it the first time. And only the super-key will bring it up.

Anyone having experienced the problem? Maybe a request in github or is this my own problem? Stay safe, and hope you have some ideas towards this!

Comment: What are your Gnome versions on both systems?

Comment: To be honest, I have given up on Fedora at this point. Really just going back to arch.